# jquery & css target nth li with varaible instead of a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jQuery to add a class to a `li` in my `ul`. This is the code:

```
$('ul').children('li:eq( '2' )').addClass('active');
```

How can I replace the "2" with a variable that is dynamic? My code below does not work. I think its a syntax issue any advice?

```
var count = 2;
$('ul').children('li:eq( 'count' )').addClass('active');
```

Comment: You can also target the element with CSS only `:nth-child(n)`, n starts from `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate your variable.

```
$('ul').children('li:eq( ' + count +' )').addClass('active');
```

However you can use [`$.fn.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
 $('ul').children('li').eq(count).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I think I like the second one better. It removes all the string concatenation, Adding a +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly add the count variable:

```
var count = 2;
$('ul').children('li:eq( ' + count + ' )').addClass('active');
```